# Window too narrow - allows only one character per line

Tags: excel, vbe

I have a weird problem in Excel's Visual Basic Editor: it shows me a very thin textfield with only one character per line and no way to alter the dimensions.
[image: Excel VBE too narrow]
Has anybody experienced a similar problem or is there a way to open macros in a text editor as a workaround?

System: Mac OS 10.11.1, Office 2016 v15.13.1, already tried reinstall.

Comment: isn't that just a container split? Can you not drag *it* to the right to see the code? Sorry I just haven't used mac in ages

Comment: Thanks, but here is nothing to drag on that edge.

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2016-macexcel/visual-basic-support-in-mac-2016/4afbba04-4435-4970-8b02-40da006a590e?auth=1

Comment: Thank you very much. According to this link Visual Basic support in Office for Mac 2016 is almost non existent. So a workaround would be to install an earlier version for the use of macros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2016-macexcel/visual-basic-support-in-mac-2016/4afbba04-4435-4970-8b02-40da006a590e?auth=1) by  Visual Basic support in Office for Mac 2016 is almost non existent. So a workaround would be to install an earlier version for the use of macros.

Thanks to [Meehow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2140173/meehow) for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

I experience the same issue.

You can copy all code, edit it in a text editor before pasting the content back into the VB Editor. It's ugly but it works.

Selecting all via Cmd+A works even if you can't visualise it.